# How to get the MySQL column datatype max length?

Tags: sql, mysql, maxlength

I'm trying to get the max length a string or integer is set to be on MySQL as a result of running a query. For instance, I have a table like this.

```
------------------
| ID  | Username |
------------------
|  1  | User1    |
|  2  | Admin    |
------------------
```

In the database the ID column is set to `int(6)` and the Username column is set to `varchar(25)`.

I would like to receive the data type and max length seperately out of a query, like:

```
INPUT:
SELECT column.name, column.type, column.length FROM myTable

OUTPUT:
----------------------------------
| Name     | Type    | MaxLength |
----------------------------------
| ID       | INT     | 6         |
| Username | Varchar | 25        |
----------------------------------
```

Is this possible at all?

I've tried the following query, but this just returns the data type. Without the amount of characters allowed.
`SELECT DATA_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE table_name = 'myTable' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'myColumn';`

I've also tried this query `SELECT COLUMN_NAME, COLUMN_TYPE FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'my_db_name' AND TABLE_NAME = 'myTable';` However this one does return the name and type with the lenght. But the length is returned like this, `varchar(25)`. I feel like there should be an easier way to retrieve the '25' than to seperate it manually from the string.

Comment: For integers this value is meaningless. Integers have fixed length in bytes.